# How to stop continuing a strpos() after it has found a result in PHP

Tags: php

Hey guys I am using the following:

```
$pos1 = strpos($currentStatus, '#');
$pos2 = strpos($currentStatus, '#', $pos1 + strlen('#'));
```

What this does is get the second hashtag if it discovers a first one and than looks for second......so It grabs that and I store it into variable and print it out.....the issue?  When I print it out I get the rest of the string so for instance:

```
$code = "Hi lets have #funfgs and than more #funny yup yup";
$pos1 = strpos($code , '#');
$pos2 = strpos($code , '#', $pos1 + strlen('#'));

echo substr($code , $pos2);
```

results: `#funny yup yup`

So I want the hashtag with the connect word to it and the rest be thrown away...how do I go about doing this?

David

EDIT:

What I want: `#funny`

Comment: what string you want to get?

Comment: Did you read documentation about [substr](http://php.net/substr)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for your worry is using [`preg_match` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

So, for your usage

```
$code = "Hi lets have #funfgs and than more #funny yup yup";
$pos1 = preg_match( "/.*#(\S+)/", $code , $match );
print_r( $match[1] );
```

---

You can include the `#` for your match too. Here is how you'd do it:

```
$pos1 = preg_match( "/.*(#\S+)/", $code , $match );
echo $match[1];
```

Comment: Hey can I do like and if statement to see if it finds a match?

Comment: Yup, @DavidBiga As mentioned in the php.net's doc on function, `preg_match()` returns **1** if the `pattern` matches given subject, **0** if it does not, or **FALSE** if an error occurred.

Comment: I just did if (!empty($match[1]))

Comment: @DavidBiga You can also have `if( preg_match( "/.*(#\S+)/", $code , $match ) )`

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$code = "Hi lets have #funfgs and than more #funny yup yup";

preg_match_all('/#(?P<hash>\w+)/',$code,$match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match['hash']);
```

Here you will get all the words after `#` you can select any word from the array `$match['hash']`

For the  case mentioned in your question use `echo $match['hash'][1];`

Comment: Nice feature about naming founded results. Tnx and +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode function:

```
$code = "Hi lets have #funfgs and than more #funny yup yup";
$pos1 = strpos($code , '#');
$pos2 = strpos($code , '#', $pos1 + strlen('#'));

$hashtag = explode(' ', substr($code , $pos2));

echo $hashtag[0];
```